# Spring and Openlayer conflicts on label rendering?

Tags: jstl, label, openlayers

I need to use Jquery to handle other elements on the webpage. I tried to put labels on a vector layer with the following style:

```
  var vector_style = new OpenLayers.Style({
            'fillColor': 'red',
            'fillOpacity': .8,
            'strokeColor': '#aaee77',
            'strokeWidth': 3,
            'pointRadius': 8,
            'label': "${name}",
            'labelAlign': "cc",
            });
```

But the labels do not show.

I am just wondering if there is a conflict on this one  "${name}".
I tested it again with a simple page without Jquery. The labels do show.
Please let me how to fix this. Thanks.

**Update:**
I just figured out the conflict may come from Spring or JSTL. I use Firebug tool to check the javaScript source code of the style. It appears as this:

```
    var vector_style = new OpenLayers.Style({
            fillColor: 'red',
            fillOpacity: .8,
            strokeColor: '#aaee77',
            strokeWidth: 3,
            pointRadius: 8,
            label: "",
            labelAlign: "cc",
            });
```

I returned an variable from the server side:

```
    model.addAttribute("name", "test");
```

then all features show the label "test".

Comment: use the `jQuery.noconflict()` and see if that helps http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: not help. I created a new web application. the web page only contains Jquery and Openlayers. It works. Seems the conflict not from Jquery. In my application which use the spring framework and Jquery, superfish and other Jquery plugins. I am not sure now where the conflict comes from.

Comment: I post new updates. Please help now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the `labelAlign` value of "`cc`" does not exist.

From the **Openlayers** documentation:

> The first character is for the horizontal alignment, the second for the vertical alignment.  ?Valid values for horizontal alignment: “l”=left, “c”=center, “r”=right.  Valid values for >vertical alignment: “t”=top, “m”=middle, “b”=bottom.  Example values: “lt”, “cm”, “rb”.  >Default is “cm”.

Try removing this line.